# Magento 2.2 error after upgrade

Tags: magento2

I have errors after the upgrade. You can see error below.

Can anyone help us to fix this error?

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
>   Line: 1139

Comment: may be extension issue

Comment: Thank you, but we have checked that already

Comment: Please cross check that block class name have backslashes if there Magento does not support backslash

Comment: You mean this? <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
   <block class=“Blue\Theme\Block\Category\Leftcategory" name="left.menu" template="Blue_Theme::callouts/leftmenu.phtml" before="-" ifconfig="blue_settings/leftcolumn/isenable" />
  </referenceContainer>

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If there is any  tag inside  tag then will though mentioned error

just remove block then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

you may search in your layout files reference for `<head>`.
Once you have found some layout files that has the `<head>` reference.

In these files, you may check that there is no block definition within the head node. If there is a block, either comment it or remove it (you may backup your layout file of course)

The reasoning is that head has indeed title subnode, css and so on.